# Finally interviewer said all the best what it means?

Tags: interview

I performed well in interview... At the end the interviewer said "All the best" what it means? I'm confused I'm selected for next round or not?

Answer (score 9):

"All the best" is a polite phrase one uses to see someone off or to wish someone luck. Not different from "goodbye" or "good luck". It contains no clues at all as to whether your interview has been successful or not.